# How to fix - urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, urlopen

I do not understand how to fix it.
I could not find anything from the Internet.

```
import re
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'getimg'):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    website = urlopen('https://nekos.life/api/hug')
    html = website.read()
    links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)
    print(links)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'get')
```

Comment: 403:forbidden so you don't have authentication or access to the site

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: there is no registration on the site

Comment: Looks like you may have to pass a [`SSLContext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) to `urlopen` to access HTTPS pages.  you should take this oppurtunity to refactor your application to use [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#client-quickstart) instead.  `urllib` is not an asynchronous library, so mixing it with `discord.py` code could lead to blocking that will crash your program.  `aiohttp` is the asynchronous web library that `discord.py` uses, so it's already on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably don’t have access to the website because you need an API key or somewhat
2. Don’t use urllib with a discord bot. Urllib is a synchronous lib while a discord bot is asynchronous so urllib will block the rest of your bot from running when making a request
   This is why aiohttp is ideally the best web requests lib for discord bots because it does run asynchronously
   I suggest you check it out it’s very simple and great

Edit: Patrick Haugh said the same thing as me before me in a comment. I just didn’t see it before writing this answer